# MVC5 UseGoogleAuthentication mysterios method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, katana

It can be a dumb question, but I did not find answer on this on Internet. I see following code for MVC5 and oAuth

app.UseFacebookAuthentication
app.UseGoogleAuthentication();

However, I don’t see any method called UseGoogleAuthentication on app object in debugger. I do see a “Use” method on AppBuilder in Katana code. So what is going on? from where this “app.UseGoogleAuthentication();” mysterious methods is coming over? I am certain I am missing some convention, but what is it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

It is an extension method, it should show up once you install Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google Nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the command 
`Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google`.

And the url is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/